# Checking Quasiconcavity?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I can't seem to understand the text's explanations with checking quasiconcavity this particular way:

A function $f(x)$, where $x$ is a vector of variables, is $\left\{\begin{array}{l}\text { quasiconcave } \\ \text { quasiconvex }\end{array}\right\}$ iff, for any constant $k$,
the set

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}S^{\geq} \equiv\{x \mid f(x) \geq k\} \\ S^{\leq} \equiv\{x \mid f(x) \leq k\}\end{array}\right\} \text { is a convex set }
$$

[image]

Problem: Check $f(x,y) = x_2 - ln (x_1) $.
Answer: Setting $x_2 - ln(x_1) = k$, and solving for $x_2$ we get isovalue equation $x_2 = ln(x_1) + k $. In the $x_1 x_2$ plan, this plots for each value of k as a log curve shifted upward vertically by the amount k.  The set $\mathbf{S}^{\leq}=\left\{\left(\mathbf{x}_{1}, \mathbf{x}_{2}\right) \mid f\left(\mathbf{x}_{1}, \mathbf{x}_{2}\right) \leq \mathbf{k}\right\}$ -- the set of points on or below the isovalue curve -- is a convex set.  Thus the function is quasiconvex (but not quasiconcave).

My Question: Below is a plot of $x_2 = ln(x_1) + 3$ where $k = 3$. I believe the idea is that the set of points corresponding to f(x) below $ k = 3 $ is a convex set. The problem I'm having is that there's also the set on or above the curve (to the left). Isn't that also a convex set (like example c above)?  The answer clearly states it doesn't so I'm doing something wrong here.  Thanks for any help.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: The epigraph of what you've drawn should correspond to $\{(x_1, x_2) \mid f(x_1, x_2) \geq k\}$ for any $k$, yes. But that epigraph is clearly non-convex -- are you having trouble with that or something else? If the only issue is seeing why the epigraph is convex, it's easy to pick two points in the epigraph of $x_2 = ln(x_1) + k$ such that the line connecting them is not wholly contained in the epigraph, which is sufficient.

Comment: @tchainzzz Right so using $\left\{\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \mid f\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \geq k\right\}$ for any k, say 3.5, there is still the entire domain in the positive x axis.  Ya my question is how this goes about confirming convexity.  I understand the traditional definitions but I'm not getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no the set of points above the curve x2 = ln(x1) + k is not convex.
look at this for instance https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPc6I.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I replaced the graph in my question with a simple drawing instead.  So, $\left\{\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \mid f\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) \geq k\right\}$ corresponds to the set of points, $x_1$, for which $f(x_1 , x_2) \geq 3$.  This would be all the points in yellow on the X axis.  Why are the points in yellow not a convex set?

Comment: {(x1,x2)∣f(x1,x2)≥k}  corresponds to the set of points, x1, for which f(x1,x2)≥3. this is wrong, it doesn't. the domain of your function is R^2. that means set of points (x1, x2) such that f(x1, x2) <= 3. so, the set of points isn't line like you're thinking. I think you are confused because the first example you showed used function of one variable. https://imgur.com/dUNlXkT